# Using xcopy to move files

Tags: windows-xp, xcopy

Having some trouble. Trying to copy some files from a network share to the local user profile for a user on XP. I'm getting an "invalid drive specification" message when I try to run my .bat script.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Below is my script:

```
@echo off &setlocal
if exist "%userprofile%\SapWorkDir\" xcopy "\\serverip\folder\" "%userprofile%\SapWorkDir\" /i /q /s /y /z && 

echo New folder 1 copied successfully || echo copied NOT successfully
```

Comment: I get that error if I enter either an wrong ip address or a non existing server name...

Comment: \\serverip\folder <-- Is this a share on the server, or is it literally a folder, for example: Going to C:\User you put in \\serverip\users?

Comment: Also, why are you checking if the folder exists locally?  Wouldn't you want to check if it exists remotely and force it down on the users machine?

Comment: These files only need to be added for users with that specific directory locally. Those users who don't have it don't need the files.

It's an actual file server, on a public share that everyone has access to.